# Is there a way to get offline tile data for Cesium?

Tags: cesium

I would like to work with Cesium (www.cesiumjs.org) without any internet connection. The documentation provide a guide for working offline and prvides a way to import tiles (see  https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/Offline-Guide). However this way does not import data to be used by the TerrainProvider.

Is there a way to provide the data locally or via local cache?
I know of the small terrain from http://cesiumjs.org/data-and-assets/terrain/small-terrain.html , However I need a finer terrain detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to serve the tiledata somehow to your application.  The STK Terrain Server is one solution that both creates and hosts tilesets.  It is not uncommon to have the terrain server hosting terrain and serving it to a Cesium app running on the same machine.

Note that the [STK Terrain Server](https://cesium.agi.com/products/stk/terrian-server/default.aspx) is a commercial application built by the primary backers of Cesium.  We do offer demo licenses if you'd like to try it out.

Comment: Is there an option to do so without the STK terrain server? I might not have the processing power to run STK terrain server on the machine. Also - are you working for AGI?

Comment: Hi, yes I do work for AGI.  There is very little computation involved in hosting the terrain.  All processing is done upfront when you're building the tileset.  Once you have a tileset, the Terrain Server simply fetches the tile data from the database and sends it to the client.

Comment: I can confirm your solution works. I was hoping for something sipler though ;)

Comment: using docker it is not complicated: "docker run -d --name cesium-terrain-server -p 8080:80 -v /MYHOSTGEODATA/tilesets/terrain:/data/tilesets/terrain geodata/cesium-terrain-server:v0.4.0" I use 0.4 because the newer versions are missing a webserver. I'm looking into it. see https://hub.docker.com/r/geodata/cesium-terrain-server/

Comment: is there any way to generate cesium tiles for GLTF or .OBJ file?

Answer (score 3):

create some TMS, Google XYZ or mbtiles with map tiler or tilemill and serve those locally with tileserver-php or portable basemap server as a WMTS

Comment: Care to add some links? I am playing with geoserver to get some results...

Answer (score -1):

You can try here and even produce your custom terrain.

You can preview and download server software for free aswell

https://portal.terrainserver.com

Note: I am the provider for that service